# My Magento only can load the first front page, and all the page are 404. Nginx server configuration issue

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, magento, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run Magento 2 on WSL, ubuntu Nginx webserver, localhost I only able to load my website first front page, but the rest of the pages are 404 not found. I only modify the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file. Since I am using localhost and only 1 site. I guess I don't need to create another one. Can anyone help me out to see what's wrong with my configuration file? /etc/nginx/sites-available/default. I am not familiar with Nginx, I did try google many days, still can't find any solution.

I am appreciate if anyone can help.

```
  # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html/Magento2_PAUL;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                # proxy_http_version 1.1;
                # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                # proxy_set_header Host $host;
                # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#              try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#
```

Comment: Check the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

instead of

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Comment: you are my life saver!